# How to access a grid using ArcObgect

Tags: grid, distance, arcobjects

How can I get value of each cells of grid using ArcObject?
Grid was created by
Spatial Analyst -> Distance ->Straight Line
I need to use this values for other operations.
Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

see http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=58550&m=148036#147741